# Using IIF statement to prevent records moving over in CSV format

Tags: sql, csv, etl

I am currently when using an ETL tool (Clover) to output a table in CSV format.

The ID field is originally inputted like so : "12,13" or "12"

And CVS formats this to 2 separate fields, messing up the entire table.

I am aware that I need to use " " to however presented with an error message when I try:

```
iif(isnull(ID), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for quote characters in metadata you use when writing to a file
http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/advanced/content.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/metadata-from-flat-file.html

BTW you could use nvl function instead of iif. nvl(var,'valueifvarempty')